# WPF - Open a Web Page passing it parameters

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to open a web page from my WPF app and also pass to the webpage certain parameters that are needed by a JavaScript function. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way. There's a control called WebBrowser in which you can set up the property "source" with the Uri of the page you want to navigate and casting this control to (WebBrowser) can calls the function .InvokeScript("NAME OF THE FUNCTION",Object PARAMETERS). It is really useful!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be submitting the parameters via the url (GET). If you want to display the webpage inside a WPF `WebBrowser` control, simply do a `myWebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.exapmle.com?parameter=bla&another=bli")`.

If you want to start the external Webbrowser, take a look at this tutorial [here](http://devtoolshed.com/content/launch-url-default-browser-using-c).

If you, on the other hand, want to send post requests directly to the website, take a look at [this](http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post).

Comment: I found another way. There's a control called WebBrowser in which you can set up the property "source" with the Uri of the page you wanna navigate and casting this control to (WebBrowser) can calls the funtion  .InvokeScript("NAME OF THE FUNCTION",Object PARAMETERS). It is really usefull!